# What are the benefits of using WaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject in a loop?

Tags: asynchronous, vector, synchronization, waitforsingleobject, waitformultipleobjects

I have a `vector<HANDLE>`. I want to wait for all of them to finish. I don't want to copy them over to an array. What are the benefits of doing so anyway and using `WaitForMultpleObjects`, rather than using `WaitForSingleObject` in a loop if any?

Thanks!

Comment: Off the top of my head, the `WaitForMultipleObjects` function allows you to wait for **all** of the objects to finish, whereas `WaitForSingleObject` only waits for a single object to finish. Which one you use depends on which behavior you require. Is there more to the question than this?

Comment: With `WaitForMultpleObjects()` you can also observe events happening one by one. With `WaitForSingleObject()` you can't always observe events in the order of occurrence, unless, the timeout is set to the minimum, which would make the use of `WaitFor*Object*()` pointless because of effectively degrading it to polling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in every C++ compiler I know of, vectors are internally an array, and you can get a pointer to the array with `&yourvector[0]`. In C++11 I believe this behavior is also required by the standard. So there's no need to copy.

As for the benefit, `WaitForMultipleObjects` will reduce the number of times you wake up, saving some small amount of CPU time. It will also atomically acquire all of the `HANDLE`s at the same time - if you have a bunch of mutex or semaphore objects and need to lock them all, this can be important.